# Returning a value from insert method

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a method that uses passed in variables to insert into the DB, I am using table adapters.

This is what I have:

```
public bool Insert(string fname, string lname)
    {
        try
        {

            peopleTableAdapters.PeopleTableAdapter peopleTA= new peopleTableAdapters.PeopleTableAdapter();
            peopleTA.insertQuery(fname, lname);


        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

In another class I want to retrieve whether the insert has been successful or not, I understand I would need to return something in the try statement in the Insert method, however what would I return for an insert query?

Comment: Given the function signature... I'd assume you'd return true...then false in the case of the exception you're swallowing...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not to hide an exception, and catch Exceptions in the client code.

```
public void Insert(string fname, string lname)
{
    peopleTableAdapters.PeopleTableAdapter peopleTA= new peopleTableAdapters.PeopleTableAdapter();
    peopleTA.insertQuery(fname, lname);
}
```

And in client code:

```
/* previous code */
try
{
   Insert("a", "b");
}
catch(Exception e) 
{
    //code when insert fails
}
```

Comment: In this case, I would not need to return anything right?

Comment: @Samrikan Correct. Ideally you'd log the exception in your catch block, then rethrow it for the higher level code to decide what to do with it.

Comment: @mason I have an error with this, could you please try to answer my new question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462794/error-when-returning-in-method Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should return **True** or **False** from the insert method. Simple as below,

```
    public bool Insert(string fname, string lname)
    {
        try
        {
            peopleTableAdapters.PeopleTableAdapter peopleTA= new peopleTableAdapters.PeopleTableAdapter();
            peopleTA.insertQuery(fname, lname);

            // return true since no exception occured
            return True;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return False;
        }
    }
```

May be you need to get the exception as well, in  that case try below,

```
public bool Insert(string fname, string lname, out string message)
{
    string message = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        peopleTableAdapters.PeopleTableAdapter peopleTA= new peopleTableAdapters.PeopleTableAdapter();
        peopleTA.insertQuery(fname, lname);

        // return true since no exception occurred
        message = "Success!";
        return True;

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        message = "Error! "+ ex.Message.ToString();
        return False;
    }
}
```